# Using multiple functions in python

Tags: python

I am having trouble trying to input an area and parameter of a triangle using multiple functions. I just started learning defining functions and can't figure this out.  The perimeter works just fine. I kept moving the hp equation around, but no luck. The area portion has me out of ideas, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
def perimeter(a,b,c):
    return a + b + c

def area(hp, a, b, c):
    return (hp * (hp - a) * (hp - b) * (hp - c)) ** (1/2)

def main():
    a = eval(input("Enter side 'a': "))
    b = eval(input("Enter side 'b': "))
    c = eval(input("Enter side 'c': "))

    hp = perimeter / 2
    per = perimeter(a,b,c)
    areaTri = area(hp,a,b,c)

    print("\n",per)
    print(areaTri)

main()
```

```
Error message: line 22, in main
    hp = perimeter / 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'int'
```

Comment: ```hp = perimeter((a,b,c)) / 2```

Comment: `hp = perimeter(a,b,c) / 2`

Comment: @pinkspikyhairman the double parentheses will cause it to interpret the argument as a tuple, rather than three separate arguments

Comment: thanks everyone, much appreciated

Comment: Don't use `eval()` for this! You likely just need `int()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the variable `perimeter` refers to the function you defined above, so when you do the line `hp = perimeter / 2` you're trying to divide a function by an integer, as the error says. If you want to divide the *return value* of the function instead, you need to call the function:

```
per = perimeter(a,b,c)
hp = per / 2
```